# How to set space as separator char while using Text::CSV::Slurp

Tags: perl, text

The text file is shown as below:

```
Interface IP-Address OK? Method Status Protocol
FastEthernet0/0 10.35.195.1 YES NVRAM up up
FastEthernet0/1 unassigned YES manual up down
SSLVPN-VIF0 10.35.195.1 YES unset up up
Loopback0 10.35.255.193 YES NVRAM up up
Loopback1 10.35.255.196 YES NVRAM up up
Loopback2 10.35.255.201 YES NVRAM up up
Loopback3 10.35.255.211 YES NVRAM up up
```

the separator char is white space instead of "," which is the default implement in `Slurp`. 
How to make it happen?

I tried `sep_char` as shown below, but failed.

```
my $data = Text::CSV::Slurp->load(file => 'table.txt',sep_char >= 0x20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax issue.

That should be a `=>` after `sep_char`, not `>=`. Also, a simple `sep_char => ' '` should be sufficient (instead of `0x20`).

Answer (score 0):

The Text::CSV::Slurp uses the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module to parse the lines of the file.
The load method you used passes the options to the [constructor of Text:CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.97/CSV_XS.pm#new), you may have a typo:

```
my $data = Text::CSV::Slurp->load(file => 'table.txt', sep_char => ' ');
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Text::CSV_XS is not designed to detect the characters used to quote and separate fields. The parsing is done using predefined settings.